# What is the column strength of Steel Pipe?

Tags: engineering, welding, trailer

I'm looking to compare how much weight a 4ft heigh column made of 1.5" steel pipe (1.9" OD, sch 40) hold vs a 2" pipe (sch 40, OD 2.375")

Comment: The 2 inch will hold more than the 1.5 inch.  The weight above will tell which one you want.  If in doubt go big or go home.

Comment: are you asking about concentric load

Comment: Concentric load on pipe is wall thickness dependent

Comment: I am guessing "column" means end to end. Correct?

Comment: Give us an idea of what you're expecting to support with this pipe.

Comment: https://mechanicalc.com/calculators/column-buckling/